# Pontrjagin duality of finite nonabelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, vector-spaces

I know Pontrjagin duality for groups has, to some extent, analogies with vector space duality/orthogonal complements, but if the groups are finite and *nonabelian*, I was wondering if such properties could still hold. First, let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension $n$ over a finite field $k$, and let $W$ be a linear subspace of dimension $m$. Then $\widehat{V} \cong V$ (the former denoting the vector space dual of $V$), and $W^{\perp}$ (the orthogonal complement of $W$ in $\widehat{V}$) has dimension $n - m$ in $\widehat{V}$. Do similar properties hold for finite abelian and nonabelian groups ? For instance, suppose $P$ is a finite nonabelian $p$-group for some prime $p$, and suppose $Q$ is a subgroup of $P$. Can something be concluded about the size (and structure) of $Q^{\perp}$ (or a similar object) in $\widehat{P}$  (where $\widehat{P}$ now denotes the Pontrjagin dual of $P$, etc.) ?

-- Thanks

Comment: How do you define $Q^\perp$ and $\widehat{P}$ in non-Abelian case?

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov: $\widehat{P}$ is defined as $\mathrm{hom}(P,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, the latter coming with pointwise addition of homomorphisms; I would define $Q^{\perp}$ as the subgroup of $\widehat{P}$ which vanishes on $Q$.

Comment: In these definitions the equality $\widehat{\widehat{P}}\cong P$ can't be true for non-Abelian groups, since $\widehat{\widehat{P}}$ will be always Abelian.

Comment: I think, you should take a look at the Tannaka-Krein duality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaka%E2%80%93Krein_duality. Maybe the introduction to this my paper will be useful as well: https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3205

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov: I know, if I am not mistaken, $\mathrm{hom}(P,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathrm{hom}(P/[P,P],\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$; still, I am wondering if some interesting conclusions could be made about $Q^{\perp}$ ...

Comment: You get informations about the abelianization of your groups...

Comment: I recommend to search for "Chu duality" or duality for finite dimensional Hopf algebras.